# Knockout binding issue $data shows dataItems exist but $data.dataItem shows 0 rows

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I am having a data binding problem.  I am using knockout-3.0.0.js, require-2.1.11, jquery-1.9.1.

There are two ko.observableArrays in this view model.  Both have the same data, and they are different by the implementation. One is using a ko.dirtyFlag() pattern found on KnockmeOut and the other is just a plan ko.observableArray().

If i use the plan (self.avail) observableArray, everything works great.  If I use the KnockMeOut dirtyFlag observable pattern (self.dataItems) No data shows.

In the HTML output:

```
 Length : <span data-bind="text: dataItems.length"></span>  shows a value of zero
```

In my debugging I found the following results confusing :

```
<pre class="hidden3" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

shows data in the view model for both (self.avail) and (self.dataItems).

In the Table List:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataItems>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

0 rows.

## Assuming I have no ko script errors, what would cause this to happen???

Below is the best details I could think to show:

## Thanks for looking

View Model Definition

```
define(['knockout-3.0.0', 'XXXXXMobile/knockoutExt'], function (ko, koExt) {

    var self;


    ko.dirtyFlag = function (root, isInitiallyDirty) {
        var result = function () { },
            _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
            _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

        result.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
            return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        });

        result.reset = function () {
            _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
            _isInitiallyDirty(false);
        };

        return result;
    };



function Item(id, dId, sId, dF, aF, mF, mId, dc, dm, cb, mb)
{
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.dId = ko.observable(dId);
    this.sId = ko.observable(sId);
    this.dF = ko.observable(dF);
    this.aF = ko.observable(aF);
    this.mF = ko.observable(mF);
    this.mId = ko.observable(mId);
    this.dc = ko.observable(dc);
    this.dm = ko.observable(dm);
    this.cb = ko.observable(cb);
    this.mb = ko.observable(mb);
    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}

function availData(action) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: action,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("in copy");
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(result, function (r) {
                var ri = new Item(r.ID, r.DEVICE_TYPE_ID, r.SYSTEM_ID, r.DISPLAY_FLAG, r.ACTIVE_FLAG, r.MESSAGE_FLAG, r.MESSAGE_ID, r.DATE_CREATED, r.DATE_MODIFIED, r.CHANGED_BY, r.MODIFIED);
                self.dataItems().push(ri);
            });
            self.avail(result);
        },
        error: function (rsult) {
            console.log(rsult);
        }
    });
}

function availabilityViewModel() {
    self = this;

    self.dataItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.avail = ko.observableArray();

    self.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.dataItems(), function (r) {
            return r.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
        });
    }, this);

    self.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.dirtyItems().length > 0;
    }, this);


    //self.fetchedData = koExt.asyncDependentObservable(function () {
    //    return $.ajax("/api/CSWAvailability/", {
    //        jsonpCallback: "availabilityResponse",
    //        dataType: "jsonp",
    //        data: { per_page: pageSize }
    //    }).then(function (data) { return data[1]; });
    //}, this);


};


return {
    init: function () {
        availData('/api/CSWAvailability/');

    },
    viewModel: availabilityViewModel
}


});
```

## HTML

```
Length : <span data-bind="text: dataItems.length"></span>. <br />
<pre class="hidden3" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.dataItems(), null, 2)"></pre>

<div id="x1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed db1Table">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Dev</th>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Disabled</th>
                <th>Show Message</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataItems">
            <tr>

                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td data-bind="text: id"></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

## WEBPAGE Output

Mobile Control Switch 
 Show Values / ID's Length : 0.

```
[]

{
  "dataItems": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "dId": 100,
      "sId": 1,
      "dF": true,
      "aF": true,
      "mF": false,
      "mId": 1,
      "dc": "2013-02-05T10:01:27",
      "dm": "2014-02-18T09:08:04.23"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "dId": 101,
      "sId": 1,
      "dF": true,
      "aF": true,
      "mF": true,
      "mId": 1,
      "dc": "2013-02-05T10:02:19.167",
      "dm": "2013-05-01T15:34:58.85"
    }


],
  "avail": [
    {
      "ID": 100,
      "DEVICE_TYPE_ID": 100,
      "SYSTEM_ID": 1,
      "DISPLAY_FLAG": true,
      "ACTIVE_FLAG": true,
      "MESSAGE_FLAG": false,
      "MESSAGE_ID": 1,
      "DATE_CREATED": "2013-02-05T10:01:27",
      "DATE_MODIFIED": "2014-02-18T09:08:04.23",
      "CREATED_BY": "rmbAdmin",
      "MODIFIED_BY": "rmbAdmin"
    },
    {
      "ID": 101,
      "DEVICE_TYPE_ID": 101,
      "SYSTEM_ID": 1,
      "DISPLAY_FLAG": true,
      "ACTIVE_FLAG": true,
      "MESSAGE_FLAG": true,
      "MESSAGE_ID": 1,
      "DATE_CREATED": "2013-02-05T10:02:19.167",
      "DATE_MODIFIED": "2013-05-01T15:34:58.85",
      "CREATED_BY": "rmbAdmin",
      "MODIFIED_BY": "rmbAdmin"
    }
  ],
  "dirtyItems": [],
  "isDirty": false
}
```

### #   Dev Module  Message Active  Disabled    Show Message

Comment: use dataItems().length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way you push the data. Please replace

```
self.dataItems().push(ri);
```

with:

```
self.dataItems.push(ri);
```

Here is the explanation: by using the parenthesis after self.dataItems you're unwrapping the knockout observableArray and return the underlying JavaScript array. By unrapping the array, the implementation of “push” which you’re calling is the default JavaScript implementation, which won't notify any knockout observers of the additional item being added to the array. The Knockout array manipulation functions are part of the observableArray, so in order to use them you don’t want to unwrap the array.
And, as Robert Slaney commented, make sure you replace

```
dataItems.length
```

with

```
dataItems().length
```

Comment: Nice Flavia!  :>  you made my day.